# How do I use Jbutton listener to pass string to another class

Tags: swing, listener, jbutton, jlabel

How do I use **Jbutton listener to get text/string from JTextField in class A and pass the string to class B**. I want to access that text in class B where I can perform other manipulation on that string.
please suggest **some code for me**

Comment: what is a "Jbutton listener"? Please learn your technical vocabulary, f.i. by reading and understanding a basic Swing tutorial like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html. Plus read the faq of this site, particularly the section about asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Take a field `private String value;` in `class B`

write its setter getter.

take reference to `class B`'s object and pass value like this:

```
B obj = new B();  make new one or whatever your object is

obj.setValue(textField.getText());
```

put this inside `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`